# Strings from messages bundles are losing UTF-8 coding

Tags: grails, internationalization

When I run my application in dev mode (`gradle bootRun`) all strings from i18N have proper encoding - I mean all polish letters are in place.

On the other hand, if I start my integration test (`gradle integrationTest`) or build WAR and deploy it on Tomcat all "special" characters are encoded invalid, i.e.: `zażółć gęślą jaźń. ZAŻÓŁĆ GĘŚLĄ JAŹŃ!` -> `za?�?? g??l? ja??. ZA?�?? G??L? JA??!`.

Also I checked it in chrome dev console - invalid strings are coming from the server, so it's (probably) not problem of HTML encoding tags, etc.

I'm using Grails 3.0.x + AngularJS

Comment: Could you show a fragment from messages_pl.properties? I used to have similar problem which was connected with Netbeans IDE; it was changing encoding during packing project.

Comment: I have just normal text in it, i.e.: ```loginUser.username.unique=Istnieje już użytkownik z podanym adresem email!```

How did you fixed this problem with packaging? Right now I'm building from IntelliJ with Gradle (on XUbuntu)

Comment: Changing encoding in IDE config or system config didn't help, I changed IDE. Does problem occur if you package it from console, too?

Comment: Still got the same problem when bundling on XUbuntu machine :/

Comment: Can you upload your project's grails-app/config + grails-app/i18n directories on github?

Comment: OK, later today will try to do this

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this particular issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and it appearred that root cause of it was in IDE i used.

Try change text encoding for messages_xx files to UTF-8.
For IntelliJ IDEA - this could be done via: http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-individual-file-encoding.html?origin=old_help

For other IDEs also should be a way -or just use text editor that supports changing file encodings.

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for this since a month ago!